# What is the query to print date along with timestamp in sql?

Tags: sql

There is a column whose datatype is Date. While showing the results, it has to display date along with the time. How to give that in query?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If the data type is `Date` and not e.g. `Timestamp` or `Datetime`, it is probably storing only the date and not the time, in which case the information you seek is simply not there.